# split dataframe in train, test, validate with %rate

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df_merged` which last column is a label (1 or 0). 
I have to split this dataframe in 3 sets, one with `train_percent`, and the other two with the rest (1-`train_percent`) at the same ratio (it means `0.5*(1-train_percent)`)
I can do this by the following code

```
_df1 = df_merged.query(f"{last_column_name}=='1'")  
len1 = len(_df1)
_df0 = df_merged.query(f"{last_column_name}=='0'")    
len0 = len(_df0)

vali1, tst1, tr1 = np.split(_df1, [int(0.5 * (1 - train_percent) * len1), int((1 - train_percent) * len1)])
vali0, tst0, tr0 = np.split(_df0, [int(0.5 * (1 - train_percent) * len0), int((1 - train_percent) * len0)])
vali_conc, frames2, tr_conc = [vali1, vali0], [tst1, tst0], [tr1, tr0]
```

But what happen if my last column has more than 2 values? I would like to split into those 3 sets and keep data proportional to  each value for the last column

Answer (score 0):

Let us do `groupby` with for loop

```
vali_conc=[]
frames2=[]
tr_conc=[]
for x , y in df.groupby('last_column_name'):

    vali1, tst1, tr1 = np.split(y, [int(0.5 * (1 - train_percent) * len1), int((1 - train_percent) * len1)])
    vali_conc.append(vali1)
    frames2.append(tst1)
    tr_conc.append(tr1)
```